# How to replace values in pandas DataFrame respecting index alignment

Tags: python, replace, pandas, alignment

I want to replace some missing values in a dataframe with some other values, keeping the index alignment.
For example, in the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.repeat(['a','b','c'],4), 'B':np.tile([1,2,3,4],3),'C':range(12),'D':range(12)})
df = df.iloc[:-1]
df.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)
df.loc['b'] = np.nan
df

      C   D
A B        
a 1   0   0
  2   1   1
  3   2   2
  4   3   3
b 1 NaN NaN
  2 NaN NaN
  3 NaN NaN
  4 NaN NaN
c 1   8   8
  2   9   9
  3  10  10
```

I would like to replace the missing values of 'b' rows matching them with the corresponding indices of 'c' rows. 
The result should look like

```
      C   D
A B        
a 1   0   0
  2   1   1
  3   2   2
  4   3   3
b 1   8   8
  2   9   9
  3   10  10
  4 NaN NaN
c 1   8   8
  2   9   9
  3  10  10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**fillna**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) with the values dictionary [**to_dict**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) from relevant `c` rows, like this:

```
# you can of course use .loc
>>> df.ix['b'].fillna(value=df.ix['c'].to_dict(), inplace=True)
    C   D
B
1   8   8
2   9   9
3  10  10
4 NaN NaN
```

Result:

```
>>> df
      C   D
A B
a 1   0   0
  2   1   1
  3   2   2
  4   3   3
b 1   8   8
  2   9   9
  3  10  10
  4 NaN NaN
c 1   8   8
  2   9   9
  3  10  10
```

Comment: This is great! One question, though. When the dataframe has more columns and we want to replace nans only on a selection of the columns, this method does not work because subsetting the dataframe creates a copy, not a view. What do you recommend doing, then?

Comment: @pauper, right off my head I will say filter the selection of the columns, then apply the same on the values copy